# how to use try catch for zend dbtable delete

Tags: zend-framework

Should I use a try catch in following code snippet. I think if zend can't delete a row or exception it will return integer (0). So what is better and why?

```
$statusDbObj = new Tracker_Model_DbTable_Status();
$where =  $statusDbObj->getAdapter()->quoteInto('tracking_number = ?', $airwaybill_number);
$delete = $statusDbObj->delete($where);
if($delete > 0)
{  
   // do something
}
else
{
   // not deleted
}
```

Here is with try catch:

```
   try
   {   
     $statusDbObj = new Tracker_Model_DbTable_Status();
     $where =  $statusDbObj->getAdapter()->quoteInto('tracking_number = ?', $airwaybill_number);
     $delete = $statusDbObj->delete($where);

     if($delete > 0)
     {  
       // do something
     }
   }
   catch (Exception $e)
   {
     // not deleted and print error
   }
```

I am new in using try catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of issues you want to address:

- Just using the `delete` result will help you detect "expected issues" (i.e., when you couldn't delete entries because they didn't match the `where` expression).
- If you use also the `try` - `catch` structure (for instance, catching a `Zend_Db_Exception`, which is likely to be thrown by the `delete` method), you'll be also able to detect "unexpected issues" (for instance, if the DB connection failed). If you omit this structure, eventual exceptions will pop up to the caller of your code, and you'll also need to address them somewhere.

Hope that helps,

Comment: For second issue, did you mean to use try-catch block?

Comment: Yes, my point it that you need to use both, to be sure that you'll be able to consider all possible errors. It's just that you can get different kinds of errors, and you need to address them differently. An exception is usually a runtime error, while a return value might be or not an error, it depends on your application.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will use try-catch here for catching DB connection failure or other eventual exceptions.